# Microsoft Teams tab is unable to save settings during the adding to a channel

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

**Context:**

I try to write a simple Microsoft Teams tab that displays a feed list.
I'm able to side load my tab to Teams and to select it from the Channel "+" menu.

**Problem:**

If I want to save my settings, an error text appears that says "We couldn't save your tab settings. Please try again." There is no error in my browser's javascript error console.

**My config.html tab javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function (saveEvent) {

        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            entityId: "example",
            contentUrl: "https://example.com/tab.html",
            suggestedDisplayName: "example",
            websiteUrl: "https://example.com",
            removeUrl: "https://example.com/remove.html"
        });

        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });

    function onClick() 
    {
        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
    }
</script>
```

**My manifest.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v0.4/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "0.4",
  "id": "ee90834a-d649-458d-a4e2-0b0f8d425c11",
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "WINSider Community Deutschland",
  "developer": {
      "name": "WINSider Community Deutschland",   
      "websiteUrl": "https://windowscommunity.de",
      "privacyUrl": "https://windowscommunity.de/de/impressum/",
      "termsOfUseUrl": "http://windowscommunity.de/de/impressum/"
  },
  "tabs" : [{
    "id": "ee90834a-d649-458d-a4e2-0b0f8d425c11",
    "name": "WINSider Community",
    "description" : {
      "short": "WINsider article list as a tab",
      "full": "Summarizes the windowscommunity.de blog posts as a clickable list."
    },
    "icons": {
      "44": "icon44.png",
      "88": "icon88.png"
    },
    "accentColor" : "#37A3CF",
    "configUrl": "https://tscholze.github.io/public/teamstab/config.html",
    "canUpdateConfig": true
  }],
  "needsIdentity": false,
  "validDomains": [
      "*.github.io",
      "*.github.com",
      "*.googleapis.com",
      "*.microsoft.com",
      "*.rss2json.com",
      "*windowscommunity.de"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your information**

David posted the answers as a comment to my [Github issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-get-started/issues/13). Thank you.

*Long story short*
`*example.org` to allow domain calls like `http://example.org` and `http://www.example.org` is not a valid definition oaf a `validDomain`.

Comment: The link posted is no longer valid - how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your `contentUrl`, `websiteUrl`, and `removeUrl` are using domains not in your `validDomains` list. This will cause the save to fail.

Comment: Sorry for doubleposting this answer. The `example.org` urls were intended to work as anonym placeholder. Sorry for this mismatch. The contentUrl, websiteUrl, and removeUrl are linked to the `tscholze.github.io/.../page.html` stuff.